# Using unmanaged C lib with C#

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling

I'm using a C lib with C#.
This is the prototype of the function that I want to use:

```
heatmap_render_default_to(const heatmap_t* h, unsigned char* colorbuf)
```

This function is allocating memory for colorbuf like this:

```
colorbuf = (unsigned char*)malloc(h->w*h->h * 4);
```

to call my function from c# I tried at first to create an unmanaged memory like this:

```
 string image = "";
 //allocate from COM heap           
 Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(image);
 GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(image, GCHandleType.Pinned);
 HeatMap.HeatMapWrapper.NativeMethods.Render_default_to(hmPtr, image);
```

But I'm getting this exception:
*Exception thrown at 0x0F17263A (EasyDLL.dll) in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x01050000.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.*

It's the first time that I try to integrate an unmanaged library in c#.

Could someone help me with this ?

Pinvoke:

```
[DllImport(DLL, EntryPoint = "heatmap_render_default_to", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern string Render_default_to(IntPtr h, byte[] colorbuf);  
[DllImport(DLL, EntryPoint = "heatmap_render_to", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern string Render_to(IntPtr h, IntPtr colorscheme, byte[] colorbuf);
[DllImport(DLL, EntryPoint = " heatmap_render_saturated_to", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern string Render_saturated_to(IntPtr h, IntPtr colorscheme, float saturation, byte[] colorbuf);
```

this is C code:

```
__declspec(dllexport) unsigned char* __cdecl heatmap_render_default_to(const heatmap_t* h, unsigned char* colorbuf)
{
return heatmap_render_to(h, heatmap_cs_default, colorbuf);
}
__declspec(dllexport) unsigned char* heatmap_render_to(const heatmap_t* h, const heatmap_colorscheme_t* colorscheme, unsigned char* colorbuf)
{
return heatmap_render_saturated_to(h, colorscheme, h->max > 0.0f ? h->max : 1.0f, colorbuf);
}
__declspec(dllexport) unsigned char* __cdecl heatmap_render_saturated_to(const heatmap_t* h, const heatmap_colorscheme_t* colorscheme, float saturation, unsigned char* colorbuf)
{
unsigned y;
assert(saturation > 0.0f);
/* For convenience, if no buffer is given, malloc a new one. */
if (!colorbuf) {
    colorbuf = (unsigned char*)malloc(h->w*h->h * 4);
    if (!colorbuf) {
        return 0;
    }
}

/* TODO: could actually even flatten this loop before parallelizing it. */
/* I.e., to go i = 0 ; i < h*w since I don't have any padding! (yet?) */
for (y = 0; y < h->h; ++y) {
    float* bufline = h->buf + y*h->w;
    unsigned char* colorline = colorbuf + 4 * y*h->w;

    unsigned x;
    for (x = 0; x < h->w; ++x, ++bufline) {
        /* Saturate the heat value to the given saturation, and then
        * normalize by that.
        */
        const float val = (*bufline > saturation ? saturation : *bufline) / saturation;

        /* We add 0.5 in order to do real rounding, not just dropping the
        * decimal part. That way we are certain the highest value in the
        * colorscheme is actually used.
        */
        const size_t idx = (size_t)((float)(colorscheme->ncolors - 1)*val + 0.5f);

        /* This is probably caused by a negative entry in the stamp! */
        assert(val >= 0.0f);

        /* This should never happen. It is likely a bug in this library. */
        assert(idx < colorscheme->ncolors);

        /* Just copy over the color from the colorscheme. */
        memcpy(colorline, colorscheme->colors + idx * 4, 4);
        colorline += 4;
    }
}

return colorbuf;
```

}

Comment: `unsigned char*` != `string`

Comment: this is odd. you are allocating memory for image (colorbuf param) but you say that the c code mallocs it. Which is it? And what about hmptr? Show the pinvoke declaration and all the calling code

Comment: The function [doesn't allocate the memory](https://github.com/lucasb-eyer/heatmap/blob/99b8fa0670463e5c619c514a4805989d3c3af75e/heatmap.c#L189) if `colorbuf` doesn't evaluate to false. If you just pass `IntPtr.Zero`, it should allocate a buffer **for** you and return a pointer to it.

Comment: The P/Invoke should be using `byte*` or `byte[]` instead of `String` for the parameter. Since C doesn't have a byte type, it typically uses char buffers (which are also used to represent strings), but in this case it's not a string, but a byte buffer. The return value cannot be a byte array, though, since the marshaller has no way of knowing its size. So it has to be a pointer (either `byte*` or simply `IntPtr`).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `heatmap_render_default_to` wants a block of bytes to write its output to. These bytes must be either allocated on the native heap (e.g. via `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`), or pinned by the GC so that they don't move while the C function is being called.

An example:

```
var colourbuf = new byte[width * height * 4];
fixed (byte* colourbufPtr = colourbuf)
    heatmap_render_default_to(hmPtr, colourbufPtr);
// Now you can play with the bytes in colourbuf
```

Or if the P/Invoke declares the function to accept `byte[]`, the GC pinning should be done for you during the marshaling of the call. So simply:

```
var colourbuf = new byte[width * height * 4];
heatmap_render_default_to(hmPtr, colourbuf);
```

The reason that you got an access violation is that you were passing in the native ANSI bytes that correspond to a string of length 0 (so, a buffer containing a single null byte) to a function that expects a large byte buffer (and thus wrote past the end of it).

Also, be extra sure that your calling convention and marshaling parameters (especially for strings) are set properly on the P/Invoke import.

In general, if you have to work with a C API for more than a trivial amount of calls, I find it's much easier to drop down into C++/CLI and write a manged-native wrapper assembly, then consume that from C# as a managed assembly.

Comment: I tried this Cameron and now I'm getting a memory segmentation damaged exception !