# Using external C++ library with C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke

I'm trying to include an external C++ library in my c# project.
This is the prototype of the function that I want to use:

```
 unsigned char* heatmap_render_default_to(const heatmap_t* h, unsigned char* colorbuf)
```

This function is allocating memory for colorbuf :

```
colorbuf = (unsigned char*)malloc(h->w*h->h * 4);
```

Pinvoke:

```
[DllImport(DLL, EntryPoint = "heatmap_render_default_to", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern byte[] Render_default_to(IntPtr h, byte[] colorbuf);
```

I tried to use this function in a main method to test the library:

```
           var colourbuf = new byte[w * h * 4];
        fixed (byte* colourbufPtr = colourbuf)
            HeatMapWrapper.NativeMethods.Render_default_to(hmPtr, colourbuf);
```

When I try this I'm getting a Segmentation fault exception.
Could someone help me with this ?

Comment: How is this one different from your previous questions, http://stackoverflow.com/q/35564802/993547 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/35517164/993547?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to marshal the return value manually. Declare it as `IntPtr`:

```
[DllImport(DLL, EntryPoint = "heatmap_render_default_to", 
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr Render_default_to(IntPtr h, byte[] colorbuf);
```

You can copy the buffer using `Marshal.Copy`:

```
IntPtr buffPtr = Render_default_to(...);
var buff = new byte[w * h * 4];
Marshal.Copy(buffPtr, buff, 0, buff.Length);
```

You'll also need to arrange for the external code to export a deallocator for the unmanaged memory that is being returned. Otherwise you'll end up leaking this memory.

I'm assuming that you are managing to pass a `heatmap_t*` correctly in the first argument of `Render_default_to`. We cannot see any of your code to do that and it's perfectly plausible that you are getting that wrong also. Which could lead to a similar runtime error.